# Class member variable validation

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the most elegant and/or idiomatic way to validate class member variables in dart?

This is what I have so far, and it works, but it seems like there should be a better way.

```dart
class Location {
  double longitude;
  double latitude;

  Location(this.longitude, this.latitude) {
    if (longitude < -180.0 || longitude > 180.0) {
      throw Exception("longitude must be between -180 and 180 degrees");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would make one of those comparisons include equal, so that halfway around the earth has only one representation, not two.

Comment: In this case, alternatively consider normalizing longitude to be within the desired range.  For example, something like: `longitude = (longitude + 180) % 360 - 180` (or if you prefer 180 over -180: `longitude = -((-longitude + 180) % 360 - 180)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ideal and better way to ensure that the class is fine to continue working is using the [assert keyword](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert).

the condition in the `assert` should be `true` in order to allow continuation of the code, otherwise, it will throw an `AssertException` with the text written in it.

Note that I wrote the opposite of your condition (which it should be true so the code works fine ).
in your case:

```
class Location {
  double longitude;
  double latitude;

 Location(this.longitude, this.latitude)
      : assert(
          longitude >= -180.0 && longitude <= 180.0,
          "longitude must be between -180 and 180 degrees",
        );
}
```

Comment: Using this code, if I instantiate an instance like: `Location(181, 90)`, it does not throw any exception.

Comment: try it now, I changed || with &&

Comment: @Mr.Brad Be aware that `assert`s are enabled only in debug builds.